# Client to do long-polling with multiple requests in a http pipeline.

Tags: http, unix, pipeline

I am looking for a client software that will run on a Unix system to do long-polling with multiple requests in a single http pipeline.

Basically we need to issue several long-polling GET requests to a server. All the requests need to be done within a single HTTP pipeline.

The client needs to have N requests open at any given time, where `N > 1`.

The server will respond either with a `200 OK` or `204 No Content`.

In case of a `200 OK`, the response needs to be piped into a new process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily implemented using PHP. The [HttpRequestPool](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/httprequestpool.construct.php) can be used to build a custom client doing just that. Also see [How can I make use of HTTP 1.1 persistent connections and pipelining from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335058/how-can-i-make-use-of-http-1-1-persistent-connections-and-pipelining-from-php)

With Go it's also fairly easy, if you create the connection yourself, you just have to send all the requests and then you can read responses sequentially, and it will send it all through one http pipelined connection.

```
conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:80")
client := httputil.NewClientConn(conn, nil)

req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "/", nil)
client.Write(req)

resp, _ := client.Read(req)
```

You should do some more error checking though.

Comment: We ended up implementing it with GO. Works like a charm!